# Como executar uma tarefa num momento preciso no tempo?

Tags: code-golf

> Uma pergunta estilo [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com)

Eu fiz um programa de console para mostrar as horas, [só que são horas diferentes das que conhecemos](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swatch_Internet_Time) - e envolve uma conta bem simples.

Ele verifica o horário do sistema, e ao descobrir que um minuto se passou, ele imprime a hora atual calculada na tela.

Exemplos da saída dele:

```
35.5787037037037
35.69444444444444
36.388888888888886
```

Porém, eu gostaria que ele funcionasse um pouco melhor:

> Eu gostaria que ele tivesse a precisão de um segundo, ou de um .beat

Para isso, eu deveria poder criar uma tarefa ligada ao relógio do sistema, **para que ele me avisasse precisamente no momento que eu determinasse**.

Eu sei que é possível fazer um *loop* infinito, e verificar a hora do sistema milhares de vezes - mas não gosto muito da idéia. O ideal seria ter um *listener* que me informasse que chegou a hora de executar minha tarefa.

Isso é possível? Como fazer? (Existe alguma mágica, vudu que permita isso?)

> - Gostaria de exemplos simples, em linguagens diferentes
> - Programa de console
> - Não há necessidade de implementar a conta do .beat
> - A idéia é liberar o programa para fazer outras coisas e ter a tarefa sendo iniciada num momento preciso no tempo
> - Uma única linguagem por resposta!

---

*A conta, para quem tiver curiosidade, é essa:*
`(UTC+1segundos + (UTC+1minutos * 60) + (UTC+1horas * 3600)) / 86.4`

Comment: Você quer que, por exemplo, uma determinada função execute apenas em um determinado horário por você definido sem que haja um loop verificando o horário? Entendi certo?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss se não for possível, a melhor maneira de se fazer com o loop (que se consiga precisão). se alguma função puder abstrair o loop, melhor - se puder fazer sem o loop melhor ainda.

Comment: É possível, em Python, pelo menos. Só achei confuso a primeira parte da pergunta, em que fala de conta, hora calculada e hora diferente da que conhecemos.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss sim, por isso disse que ela não é necessária no final - o meu objetivo inicial era fazer um relógio, se isso não ficou claro, mas acho que o exercício interessante é o de consultar o horário de sistema o número de vezes necessário para fazê-lo com precisão.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss inclui a conta do beat no final da pergunta para matar a curiosidade.

Comment: Lembro do _.beat_. Foi uma jogada de _marketing_ de um relojoeiro suíço, Swatch, nos remotos tempos de 1998...

Comment: @Wtrmute fui conhecer na semana passada! vi que queriam colocar um satélite no espaço [só para servir as horas](https://www.wired.com/1999/04/swatch-saves-mir/) - insanos!

Answer (score 21):

## Python

Em Python existe o pacote [`sched`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html) que pode ser utilizado para agendar tarefas em pontos determinados do tempo. Veja o exemplo:

```py
import sched, time, threading, sys

trigger = time.mktime((2017, 6, 14, 21, 15, 36, 0, 0, 0))

def task(trigger):
    sys.stdout.write("Tarefa executada com um erro de " + str(time.time() - trigger) + ' segundos\n')

s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)

s.enterabs(trigger, 1, task, argument=(trigger,))

t = threading.Thread(target=s.run)
t.start()

while t.is_alive(): pass # Simula o programa executando normalmente
```

Para o exemplo acima, a função `task` será executada exatamente em 2017-06-14 às 21:15:36, exibindo na tela a mensagem (por exemplo):

```
Tarefa executada com um erro de 0.0057599544525146484 segundos
```

> Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/Ilfg/5)

**Referência das funções utilizadas:**

[`sched.scheduler`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html#sched.scheduler)
[`sched.scheduler.enterabs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html#sched.scheduler.enterabs)
[`sched.scheduler.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html#sched.scheduler.run)
[`time.mktime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.mktime)
[`time.time`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.time)
[`time.sleep`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep)
[`threading.Thread`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread)
[`threading.Thread.start`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.start)
[`threading.Thread.is_alive`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.is_alive)

Answer (score 10):

Em Java:

```java
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Swatch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Recebe a entrada em .beats e converte para milisegundos desde a meia-noite.
        int milisegundosAgendamento = Integer.parseInt(args[0]) * 86400;

        // Hora atual no fuso horário UTC+1.
        ZonedDateTime utc1 = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.ofHours(1));

        // Calcula a quantidade de milisegundos desde a meia-noite que se passaram neste momento.
        int milisegundosAgora = utc1.getHour() * 3600000 + utc1.getMinute() * 60000 + utc1.getSecond() * 1000 + utc1.getNano() / 1000000;

        // Calcula quantos milisegundos faltam para chegar a hora certa. O if serve para o caso de a hora certa ser amanhã, e não hoje.
        int milisegundosQueFaltam = milisegundosAgendamento - milisegundosAgora;
        if (milisegundosQueFaltam < 0) milisegundosQueFaltam += 86400000;

        // Cria um objeto responsável por executar tarefas em momentos pré-agendados.
        ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor agendador = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);

        // Agenda a tarefa de mostrar a hora e fechar o agendamento:
        agendador.schedule(() -> {
            System.out.println("Chegou a hora");
            agendador.shutdown();
        }, milisegundosQueFaltam, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
}
```

O código acima mostra a mensagem `Chegou a hora` quando chegar a hora certa. Não há verificação de erros na entrada, ele presume que receberá por linha de comando um número inteiro entre 0 e 999. Após chegar a hora certa o programa finaliza.

Entretanto, considerando [as regras originais do code-golf](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6121/132) que visam a minimização do tamanho do código-fonte, chego a esta outra versão aqui embaixo com **<s>404</s> <s>373</s> 366 bytes**. Nela, a mensagem de que a hora chegou é apenas o programa retornando o status 5 ao sistema operacional quando chegar a hora. A precisão dele é de décimos de segundo ao invés de milisegundos tal como o código acima. Novamente, não há qualquer verificação acerca de a entrada ser ou não válida:

```java
import java.time.*;import java.util.concurrent.*;class S{public static void main(String[]x){ZonedDateTime z=ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.ofHours(1));int g=Integer.parseInt(x[0])*864-z.getHour()*36000-z.getMinute()*600-z.getSecond()*10-z.getNano()/100000000;new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1).schedule(()->System.exit(5),(g<0?g+864000:g)*100,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);}}
```

Comment: `milisegundosAgora` não existe no código de cima (era `b`?) - tirando isso, gostei! (principalmente do código de baixo que fez o verificador de sintaxe do eclipse quebrar) +1

Comment: @Blogueira Arrumado. Isso daí é resultado de que eu comecei a minificar o código original, vi que estava fazendo besteira, apertei Ctrl+Z várias vezes (mas faltou uma), copiei o código aqui e então prossegui com a minificação.

Answer (score 4):

## Em C#

o mesmo pode ser feito [usando um timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx).

A parte mais complicada é tratar o caso de quando o timer deve começar. Uma vez que não existe uma API simples para fazer isso voce tem que recorrer a outros mecanismos como `Thread.Sleep`.

```cs
System.Timers.Timer StartTimer(TimeSpan interval, Action onTick, DateTime? startAt = null){
    startAt = startAt ?? DateTime.UtcNow;
    var timer =  new  System.Timers.Timer();
    timer.Interval = interval.TotalMilliseconds;
    timer.Elapsed += (ctx, arg) => onTick();
    timer.AutoReset = true;

    //evita o bloqueamento da thread chamadora.
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ctx =>{  
        //espera até que o momento atual seja aproximadamente `startAt`
        Thread.Sleep(Math.Max(0, (DateTime.UtcNow - startAt).TotalMilliseconds));
        //chama o callback e comeca o timer que vai chamar o callback em intervalos
        onTick();
        timer.Start();
    });
    return timer;
}

StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), () => Console.WriteLine("Tick"));
```

Comment: Nas suas duas respostas você entra apenas com um valor em minutos ou segundos para executar a tarefa, mas não um ponto exato na linha do tempo, correto? Se sim, acredito que da forma que está elas não respondem completamente ao que foi pedido, sendo passível, assim, de uma adaptação sua, pois a tarefa deve ser executada exatamente naquele instante independente de quando eu executar o código.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Nao. Este código apenas chama o callback em `startAt` e depois de x em x `interval`. O do javascript voce tem que calcular o delay por voce mesmo.

Comment: É justamente esse cálculo que é a adaptação do qual eu falei. Nesta resposta, a tarefa não será executada 1 minuto após eu rodar os programa? Como faria para determinar o horário exato desejado?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Nao. Isso so acontece no código do Javascript. Neste de c# se voce passar um StartAt de 2020 ele só comeca em 2020. No do Javascript voce tem que calulcar a difference entre 2020 e a data atual em milisegundos.

Answer (score 1):

## Em Javascript

Pode ser feito usando `setTimeout` e alguma recursividade.

```js
function setIntervalDelayed(delay, interval, cb){
    setTimeout(function(){
        cb();
        setIntervalDelayed(interval, interval, cb);
    }, delay);
}

setIntervalDelayed(1000, 5000, function(){console.log('Tick');});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Em C:**

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>


void callback_func( time_t t )
{
    printf("CallBack: %ld\n", t );
}


void timer( int intervalo, void (*func)(time_t) )
{
    time_t atual;
    time_t ultima;

    while(1)
    {
        atual = time(NULL);

        if( atual >= ultima + intervalo )
        {
            func( atual );
            ultima = atual;
        }

        usleep( (intervalo / 10) * 1000000L );
    }

}

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    timer( 1, callback_func );
    return 0;
}
```

Saída:

```
CallBack: 1498509557
CallBack: 1498509558
CallBack: 1498509559
CallBack: 1498509560
CallBack: 1498509561
CallBack: 1498509562
CallBack: 1498509563
CallBack: 1498509564
CallBack: 1498509565
CallBack: 1498509566
CallBack: 1498509567
CallBack: 1498509568
CallBack: 1498509569
CallBack: 1498509570
```