# Como parar um loop em um determinado horário?

Tags: python

Sou iniciante em Python e estou tentando criar um despertador... Mas ele não "Desperta" na hora certa, alguém pode me ajudar?

```
import datetime
import time

print("Digite a hora para ligar (HH:MM)")
t_desp = str(input(""))
t_desp += ":00"
print("Despertar as: ", t_desp)
while True:
    t_agora = str(datetime.datetime.now().time())
    t_agora = t_agora.split(".")
    print(t_agora[0])
    if t_agora == t_desp:
       print("Acordar")
       break
    time.sleep(1)
```

Obrigado

Comment: é melhor converter para um objeto datetime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sua lógica está correta, você só está fazendo uma grande confusão ao manipular o objeto de data/hora ao convertê-lo para string a fim de fazer a comparação dos horários!

Essa conversão não é necessária, a comparação de um objeto de data/hora pode ser feita por meio dos operadores de comparação: `>`, `<`, `==`, `!=`, `<=` e `>=`, normalmente, da mesma forma como você faria com números inteiros.

A coisa pode ser mais simples do que você imagina, veja só:

```
import datetime
import time

entrada = str(input("Digite a hora para ligar (HH:MM)"))

hr = entrada.split(':')

t_desp = datetime.datetime.combine( datetime.datetime.now().date(),
                                    datetime.time( int(hr[0]), int(hr[1])) )

print("Despertar as: ", t_desp )

while True:

    t_agora = datetime.datetime.now()

    print(t_agora)

    if t_agora >= t_desp:
       print("Acordar")
       break

    time.sleep(1)
```

Saída:

```
Digite a hora para ligar (HH:MM): 09:04
Despertar as:  2018-06-15 09:04:00
2018-06-15 09:03:52.754612
2018-06-15 09:03:53.755732
2018-06-15 09:03:54.756937
2018-06-15 09:03:55.758121
2018-06-15 09:03:56.759319
2018-06-15 09:03:57.760200
2018-06-15 09:03:58.761378
2018-06-15 09:03:59.762585
2018-06-15 09:04:00.763779
Acordar
```

Answer (score 2):

Assim como eu respondi em

[Como executar uma tarefa num momento preciso no tempo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/211990/5878)

Você não precisa criar um laço de repetição e ficar verificando o horário a cada segundo, basta você definir o agendamento da chamada a uma função no horário que você deseja.

```
import sched, time, threading, sys

# Executará no dia 2018-06-15 às 12:00:00
trigger = time.mktime((2018, 6, 15, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))

def task(trigger):
    sys.stdout.write('Trim! Trim! Hora de acordar')

s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)

s.enterabs(trigger, 1, task, argument=(trigger,))

t = threading.Thread(target=s.run)
t.start()

while t.is_alive(): pass # Simula o programa executando normalmente
```

Por exemplo, você pode fazer outras coisas no código, se precisar, enquanto o alarme não é disparado:

```
import sched, time, threading, sys

print('Para quando deseja configurar o alarme?')
year = int(input('Ano? '))
month = int(input('Mês? '))
day = int(input('Dia? '))
hour = int(input('Hora? '))
minute = int(input('Minutos? '))
second = int(input('Segundos? '))

trigger = time.mktime((year, month, day, hour, minute, second, 0, 0, 0))

def task(trigger):
    sys.stdout.write('Trim! Trim! Hora de acordar')

s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)

s.enterabs(trigger, 1, task, argument=(trigger,))

t = threading.Thread(target=s.run)
t.start()

print('Enquanto esperamos, que tal um jogo?')

while t.is_alive():
    from random import randint
    a = randint(-100, 100)
    b = randint(-100, 100)
    answer = int(input(f'Quanto vale {a}+({b})? '))
    print('Muito bem!' if a+b == answer else 'Ahm... acho que não')
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/SuspiciousAromaticArray) | [GitHub GIST](https://gist.github.com/39ef62ac5f4548a42699fbd275f37e3d)</sup>