# Alternativas para timesleep

Tags: python, python-3.x, lib

Boa Noite!
sempre o que eu uso delay ou o time.sleep o meu código ´simplesmente trava até o final da execução, até onde eu li eles não trabalham em paralelo 
existe alguma lib que tenha a mesma função de espera mas não interrompa o resto do código??? 
O objetivo do código é retornar uma tela quando a data for igual a do computador,
mas quando é adicionada a primeira entrada ele espera o fim da execução(tempo) até ser possível digitar a segunda entrada então o objetivo de chamar a tela varias vezes ao dia se torna inviável

> exemplo: sou um operador de telemarketing ligo pra algumas pessoas e elas pedem para eu retornar a ligação mais tarde, eu agendo elas e quando a hora for precisa eu tenho as telas com os dados dos mesmos.

Comment: Poderia esclarecer melhor o que você quer fazer? Se não deve travar a execução, por que precisa "esperar"? Tem como colocar exemplos na pergunta do que precisa fazer?

Comment: Se a ideia é executar um código em um determinado horário, você pode fazer o que eu respondi em [Como executar uma tarefa num momento preciso no tempo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/212997/5878)

Comment: mas eu poderia fazer isso varias vezes no mesmo dia sem quebrar o trigger inicial e sem travar o cod??

Comment: Criando múltiplas threads, sim.

Comment: acebai de testar e deu certo
 muito obrigado